# Javascript/AJAX/send to server text and file with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, upload

I'm developing a small software that allow to insert of my client's store products, description text and product photos, then i need to send with $.ajax() either text and files with 1 call.

I have no problem sending text or file separately, with 2 call, but can i do it with 1?

Answer (score 2):

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file-identifier", $('#file-identifier').get(0).files[0]);
formData.append("variable", $.session.get("variable"));
$.ajax({
    url     : "path/to/file.file",
    type    : "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data    : formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){
        //handle on success
    },
    error    : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(arguments);
   }
});
```

This is a sample from a script I used recently to upload a jpeg and a variable taking content from a session variable. Appending these to a `FormData` object allows you to transfer both file and variable in one request.

Comment: Thanks for complete answer, but I've got further problem: additional info that I wanna send (fields you named "variable") are in JSON format, and on PHP back-end through $_POST["variable"] I have only string, automatically any type is convert to string. How I can resolve this further problem?

Comment: [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is what you're looking for I think. Don't forget to accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: Sorry my friend, you gave to me a big help, Thank you. With FormData() any data are converted to a string, but i solved passing any field in POST, instead passing one JSON format. Thank you a lot